# How to reconnect Node App to new Google Cloud SQL Database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform

A development version of a react/node app is in a gcp project. This project was created by someone else who left so I have limited understanding. I need to get this app ready for production.

I took the code and copied this app over to a new project which will be used for production. Inside the server.js file I changed the host, password, and database to match the database in the new project I created.
When the do npm run build inside client and do gcloud app deploy api/app.yaml and client/app.yaml the deployed app still references the original database from the development app despite specifying new host,password, and database.

I'm guessing the problem is I originally deployed it using the dev database options, and when I switch to the prod database options, it fails to connect and reverts to the previous connection.

If this is true, how can I see what is causing this connection failure? Is there other settings I need to set in the database to make it connection ready. All I did was create a database of the same name in a new project.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'xxx',
  database: 'xxx',
  multipleStatements: true
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first potential cause is that depending on how you authenticate the connection to the Cloud SQL instance, you may have to create a new service account along a new JSON key which would be used by App Engine to connect to it. If App Engine has those credentials to the old database, that would be one root cause. [Here is how to configure this.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#4_if_required_by_your_authentication_method_create_a_service_account)

The second is that the “app.yaml” file may not be updated with the new credentials to the new database if these are set as environment variables. [Here is an example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql/app.standard.yaml) of using such configuration. Note that this example comes from [this complete tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/mysql) on connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine running Node.js. I suggest reading it in full along the example files, and compare with your current code/configuration to notice any discrepancies.

Finally, looking at the “server.js” file, there is no mention of the socketPath (located at /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME) or the TCP IP and port. [Here is an example](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_to) of such file with those configured (make sure to click the Node.js tab). Note that the App Engine standard environment uses Unix domain sockets only, while the flexible environment will also allow connecting through TCP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was in my client files I was doing get and post requests to the dev version of the app which populated the app with the wrong data.